# C# Excel 2016 VSTO Workbook Project -- Labels randomly disappear and other controls are disabled

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have an Excel VSTO Workbook Project written in C#. I'm using Excel 2016 64bit, VS 2017 Community Addition, and Windows 10 on two machines. On one machine the application behaves as expected and on the other machine the there are issues. There is a sheet that has Labels, ComboBoxes, and Buttons that control the contents of a ListObject. The Labels, ComboBoxes, and Buttons sit in a single cell at the top of the sheet above the ListObject. The ComboBoxes and the ListObject are filled from database calls. On the problem machine, when I open the sheet, some or all of the labels disappear (it's random which labels disappear) and all of the ComboBoxes and Buttons are disabled. The ListObject displays correctly and has data in both versions. When I step through the code on the problem machine there are no exceptions -- all of the data that should fill the ComboBoxes appears to be present. It seems likely that this is an environment issue. I compared the applications in Visual Studio using the modules window and the only difference was that the working version was using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities.dll and the problem version wasn't. I can generate logs using VSTO_LOGALERTS for the working version, but not for the problem version, not sure why. Any ideas about what's causing my Excel display issue or how to diagnose/fix it would be much appreciated.

Comment: On the problem machine, have you checked if there are missing references?

Comment: Is the worksheet displayed at 100% on the problem machine? WinForms controls need to display at 100% to "behave properly"...

Comment: @aduguid, yes, I've checked this ... many times :-)

Comment: @CindyMeister, yes I verified that the display is 100% on the problem machine. Thanks.